# Website dark mode change triggers video source change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom button in my WordPress Elementor page that randomly changes the video playing on the website. The URLs are defined in the back end, and the PHP code is added in the footer. Not much to it, seems to work well:

```
<?php
$all_random_urls = array();
if( have_rows('videor_random_url') ):

    while( have_rows('videor_random_url') ) : the_row();

        $sub_value = get_sub_field('add_videor_random_url');
        $all_random_urls[] = $sub_value;
        
    endwhile;

else :
    // Do something...
endif;
?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var all_datas = "";
        var new_video_url = "";
        setTimeout(function() {
            all_datas = <?php echo json_encode($all_random_urls); ?>;
            
            jQuery('#random_video_changer').on('click', function() {
                var present_video_url = all_datas[Math.floor(Math.random() * all_datas.length)];
                if(new_video_url != '' && new_video_url == present_video_url) {
                    present_video_url = all_datas[Math.floor(Math.random() * all_datas.length)];                    
                    new_video_url = present_video_url;
                    jQuery('.mdp-videor-video video.elementor-video').attr('src', new_video_url);
                } else {
                    new_video_url = present_video_url;
                    jQuery('.mdp-videor-video video.elementor-video').attr('src', new_video_url);   
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
        
    });
</script>
```

What I am trying to do now is use the dark mode toggle button from my Darklup plugin to change the video playing. I have managed to do it by changing the on-click from '#random_video_changer' to whatever the div id/class of the button is. This works but in this way it is impossible to use different videos for dark and light theme since every button click toggles a video change. I have been trying to change the following plugin js to call for video change when theme is dark or light, but I am struggling to get any results.

```
    darkModeSwitchEvent: function() {

            let $that = this;

            $(this.switchTrigger).on( 'click', function(e) {

                let $this = $(this);

                $('html').toggleClass($that.darkEnabledClass);

                // Storage data
                if( $this.is(':checked') ) {
                    localStorage.setItem("darklupModeEnabled", $that.darkEnabledClass);
                    localStorage.setItem("triggerCheked", "checked");
                    $this.closest('.darkluplite-mode-switcher').addClass('darkluplite-dark-ignore');

                    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
                        localStorage.removeItem("lightOnOSDarkCheked");
                    }
                } else {
                    $this.closest('.darkluplite-mode-switcher').removeClass('darkluplite-dark-ignore');
                    localStorage.removeItem("darklupModeEnabled");
                    localStorage.removeItem("triggerCheked");

                    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
                        localStorage.setItem("lightOnOSDarkCheked", true);
                    }
                }

            } )
```

What would be the simplest way to achieve this - when light mode is active the video is played from video array 1, when dark mode is active, video is played from video array 2?

I am trying to learn how to do this on my own but have spent few hours on this now without any movement in the right direction, so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have tried using something like this to get it to work but without success so far. Again if you can point to me what I am doing wrong I will try to learn ad fix it myself.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var all_datas = "";
        var dark_video_url = "https://matepece.com/wp-content/uploads/Shine2.mp4";
        var light_video_url = "https://matepece.com/wp-content/uploads/Mountains-59291.mp4";
        setTimeout(function() {
            all_datas = <?php echo json_encode($all_random_urls); ?>;
            
            
        
              
        if (localStorage.getItem("darklupModeEnabled") == "0") {
            
            jQuery('.mdp-videor-video video.elementor-video').attr('src', light_video_url);   
                
            
        }else if (localStorage.getItem("darklupModeEnabled") == "1"){
            
           jQuery('.mdp-videor-video video.elementor-video').attr('src', dark_video_url);   
           
        }
    
            
            
);
        }, 2000);
        
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: its unclear what you actually want, do you want different set of videos for each theme or you wanna keep playing the current video even tho the theme changes ? whenever you call `.attr('src', new_video_url);` the video will reload, the logic behind naming `new` and `present` is flipped, if you get 2x random same video you will play it again, you should have a loop to get random video until you find something else then current, you could have two lists for dark and light instead `all_datas` and simply switch between by reading `localStorage.getItem("darklupModeEnabled")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Yes, I think it is best to have two different Videos (or arrays) for dark or light theme. I've tried changing the code a bit but am still doing something wrong (added to OP)

Comment: In your "edit code" you didn't bound your "switching mechanics" to any event, the functions are executed just once at page load, `jQuery('#random_video_changer').on('click', function() {..});` is missing. You are responsible for managing the `darklupModeEnabled` at `darkModeSwitchEvent`, just take a look how you are doing it, setting: `setItem(..., $that.darkEnabledClass)` and removing: `removeItem(...)`, so just check it accordingly like: `if(localStorage.getItem("darklupModeEnabled")){...}else{...}`. Btw your parenthesis seems inconsistent. Use console to check if your code works.